# Extracting a specific area of an XML document downloaded from the internet

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

Below is a sample of an XML file my Weather app will download from the internet. The XML document contains weather data.

**What is the simplest way to extract the temperature value without all of the other XML junk around it?**

I would like to be able to use this method for any other area of the XML file such as extracting sunrise/sunset data.

If I need to, I can convert this into a string.

```
<current>
  <city id="6295630" name="Earth">
    <coord lon="0" lat="0"/>
    <country/>
    <sun rise="2013-12-23T05:55:41" set="2013-12-23T18:03:08"/>
  </city>
  <temperature value="289.58" min="285.37" max="294.26" unit="kelvin"/>
  <humidity value="99" unit="%"/>
  <pressure value="1014" unit="hPa"/>
  <wind>
    <speed value="3.11" name="Light breeze"/>
    <direction value="195.004" code="SSW" name="South-southwest"/>
  </wind>
  <clouds value="80" name="broken clouds"/>
  <precipitation value="1.53" mode="rain" unit="3h"/>
  <weather number="500" value="light rain" icon="10n"/>
  <lastupdate value="2013-12-23T23:15:11"/>
</current>
```

Comment: Thanks, Xdocument working great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath

```
/current/temperature
```

will select just the `<temperature>` node (or nodes, if there's more than one).

To get just the current temperature (which I assume is the value of the `value` attribute, you can say:

```
/current/temperature/@value
```

which will get the all the attributes named `value` that are part of the `<temperature>` node.

If you slurp your XML into an `XmlDocument`, you can use Xpath to select the desired element(s) from the document. It can be as easy as

```
string textXmlDocument = LoadXmlAsString() ;

// slurp the xml into an XmlDocument
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument() ;
xml.LoadXml( textXmlDocument) ;

// extract the temperature node
XmlNode currentTemp = xml.SelectSingleNode( @"/current/temperature") ;

// parse the value of its value attribute as a double.
string  s           = currentTemp.Attributes["value"].Value ;
double  temperature ;
bool parsed = double.TryParse(s) ;
```

One should note that the XML document is simple enough that it would be really easy to construct a class and tag it and its properties such that you could use the CLR's attribute-based XML serialization to deserialize your xml into the class...something like this incomplement and untested example:

```
[XmlRoot("current")]
public class WeatherReading
{

  [XmlElement("city")]
  public WeatherReadingCity City { get ; set ; }

  [XmlElement("temperature")]
  public WeatherReadingTemperature Temperature { get ; set ; }

}

public class WeatherReadingTemperature
{

  [XmlAttribute("value")]
  public double Current { get ; set ; }

  [XmlAttribute("min")]
  public double Minimum { get ; set ; }

  [XmlAttribute("max")]
  public double Maximum { get ; set ; }

  [XmlAttribute("unit")]
  public TemperatureScale Scale { get ; set ; }

}

public enum TemperatureScale
{
  Unknown     = 0 ,
  Fahrenheith = 1 ,
  Centigrade  = 2 ,
  Celsius     = 2 ,
  Kelvin      = 3 ,
}

public class WeatherReadingCity
{

  [XmlAttribute("id")]
  public int Id { get ; set ; }

  [XmlAttribute("name")]
  public string Name { get ; set ; }

  [XmlElement("coord")]
  public WeatherReadingPosition Position { get ; set ; }

}

public class WeatherReadingPosition
{

  [XmlAttribute("lat")]
  public double Latitude  { get ; set ; }

  [XmlAttribute("long")]
  public double Longitude { get ; set ; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Load into XmlDocument and  then extract the values..

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(yourXmlString);

XmlNode tempNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"current\temperature");
XmlAttribute attr = tempNode.Attributes["value"];

// attr.Value = now holds the string 289.58
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `XDocument` might be the easiest, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx.  This is basically LINQ for XML.

```
 XDocument doc = // load your XML into the document

 var tempValue = doc.Descendents("temperature").Attribute("value").Value;
 var tempUnit = doc.Descendents("temperature").Attribute("unit").Value;
```

Comment: Beware of `NullPointerException`s if they do not always return the temperature in the XML!

Comment: @justderb good comment.  However, I was just trying to show how to use XDocument, without all the production code.  You will most likely also want to convert temp value to a `decimal`.